# Reduce React-Native image asset size

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on an application where I have lot of images and icons(all png), I found out that the image folder's total size is close to 15MB, which is too much, as I am new to react-native so not sure how this size is impacting the total app size and also I am not sure about the best way to reduce this folder size(i.e., images/icons), should I use svg or any other format for this or is there any other way(i.e., compressing the image/icon size etc.)?

I can see that we can't able to use svg directly, we need to use some library and I don't want to burden my app with any libraries as it's already quite heavy

Thanks and looking for the best solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options to minimize your image assets bundle size.

1. Using an image URL - instead of storing images on your app. You can upload images to a server and refer the link to App. some image provider servers.

   - Cloudinary
   - Firebase Storage
2. Using SVG - you said that you don't want to include any libraries check the bundle size of [`react-native-svg`](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=react-native-svg@12.1.0) it's a pretty lightweight package.
3. Use any image compressor - compress your image and use it. you can use

   - [TinyJPG](https://tinyjpg.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Compress all images at build time using [react-native-imagemin-asset-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-imagemin-asset-plugin)